# Is builder pattern required in this scenario?

Tags: java, builder-pattern

Is builder pattern required here?

I am writing a class which needs 3 parameters to start working. I am enforcing the object creation by passing an object which will have the 3 values. I validate the parameters via a method and the class looks something like this:

```
class CustomisedHttpClient{

    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String property3;

   CustomisedHttpClient(ConfigObject configObject){
     // Setting the field values here
   }
}
```

I can pass another object in constructor which will be built using BUILDER PATTERN like this:

```
ConfigObject.build()->setUsername("")->setPassword("")->setProperty3("");
```

I will use this built object as constructor argument in the above class.

I think builder pattern is not required here since the object creation is not dependent on the properties being passed. It would be useful if there are more properties, the properties are optional and the object creation changes based on the parameters passed. Expert opinions please.

Comment: If the `ConfigObject` encapsulates the username, password, and single property,  then your client class doesn't even need a builder.  But, in that case, the `ConfigObject` class might benefit from a builder.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen benefit as in? I won't be having any additional property

Comment: I recently refactored our code with Builder Pattern because our constructor was getting way too big and clumsy. But this code seems fine to me. :)

Comment: Maybe take a step back and first try to understand why you would want to use the builder pattern.  It allows you to handle constructing a new instance of an object in a very flexible way, with any number/combination of inputs.  It also frees you from needing many different constructor signatures.  That being said, if you are very certain that you would only ever need one, or maybe just a small handful, of constructors, then don't use the builder; it would just be adding more code.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen that's exactly what I am thinking, I just needed an expert opinion so that I may discuss it with team.

Comment: Check the current usage of this class/constructor and see if it feels onerous.  If not, then perhaps vote against introducing the builder pattern.  Keep in mind that willy-nilly use of design patterns itself can be considered an anti-pattern.

Comment: Exactly my point, one of the team members actually wanted to use pattern so he used it without realizing if it's really needed or not. Thanks for the explanation @TimBiegeleisen